# SQL COUNT query similar to UNION but with results in multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a single-table SQL database built from DHCPD logs, structured as below:

```
+------+-------+------+----------+---------+-------------------+-----------------+
| id   | Month | Day  | Time     | Type    | MAC               | ClientIP        |
+------+-------+------+----------+---------+-------------------+-----------------+
| 9305 | Nov   |   24 | 03:20:00 | DHCPACK | 00:04:f2:4b:dd:51 | 10.123.246.116  |
| 9307 | Nov   |   24 | 03:20:07 | DHCPACK | 00:04:f2:99:4c:ba | 10.123.154.176  |
| 9310 | Nov   |   24 | 03:20:08 | DHCPACK | 00:19:bb:cf:cd:28 | 10.99.107.3     |
| 9311 | Nov   |   24 | 03:20:08 | DHCPACK | 00:19:bb:cf:cd:28 | 10.99.107.3     |
```

Every DHCP event from the log will eventually make its way into this database, so events from any point in time will be potentially used in the construction of graphs. To make use of the data for graphing, I need to be able to create an output table with multiple columns, but with values derived from a count of those in a single column matching a specific pattern.

The closest thing I've managed to come up with is this query:

```
select 'Data' as ClientIP, count(*) from Log where ClientIP like '10.99%' and MAC like '00:04:f2%'
union
select 'Voice' as ClientIP, count(*) from Log where ClientIP like '10.123%' and MAC like '00:04:f2%';
```

Which yields the following result:

```
+-----------+-------+
| ClientIP  | Count |
+-----------+-------+
| Data      |  4618 |
| Voice     | 13876 |
+-----------+-------+
```

Fine for a one-off query, but I want to take those two rows, turn them into two columns, and run the same query with one row per hour (for instance). I want something like this:

```
+------+-------+------+
| Hour | Voice | Data |
+------+-------+------+
|  03  |  22   |  4   |
|  04  | 123   | 23   |
|  05  |  45   |  5   |
```

Any advice is greatly welcomed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by hour and use conditional computation to count Data and Voice traffic. 
For example:

```
SELECT 
HOUR(time) AS `Hour`, 
SUM(CASE WHEN ClientIP like '10.99%' and MAC like '00:04:f2%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `Data`,
SUM(CASE WHEN ClientIP like '10.123%' and MAC like '00:04:f2%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `Voice`
FROM log
GROUP BY HOUR(time)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate table for  (as you want) :

+------+-------+------+
| Hour | Voice | Data |
+------+-------+------+

and update it every hour using triggers.